# how to make willPopScope return back not out of the app, flutter

Tags: flutter, searchbar

I have this Textfield as a search, everything works well except when the user clicks on the back button and as a result of the `onWillPopScope` it exits the app. How I can fix this to return to Menu instead?

**This is my Textfield**

[image: Textfield]

**This is what happens when I search**
[image: Exiting app]

---

TextEditingController searchController = new TextEditingController();

StreamSubscription _recipeAddedSub;

List allRecipes = [];

List searchRecipes = [];

bool _isSearching;

Recipes recipes;

```dart
var recipeRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
    void initState(){
     super.initState();
      _recipeAddedSub = recipeRef.child('recipes').onChildAdded.listen(recipesEvent);
 }

    DatabaseReference getRecipeRef(){
      recipeRef = recipeRef.root();
      return recipeRef;
    }
    
    void recipesEvent(Event event){
      //listen from firebase
      Recipes recipes = new Recipes.fromSnapShot(event.snapshot);
      setState(() {
        allRecipes.add(recipes);
      });
    }
   Future<bool> _onBackPressed() async {
   if(_isSearching ==true){
    setState(() {
      searchRecipe("");
     _isSearching = false;
     allRecipes.add(recipes);
    }); 

     return false;
   }
   else {
     return true;
   }
 }
```

**My search method:**

```dart
    void searchRecipe(String searchVal){
           _isSearching = true;
            searchRecipes.clear();
          setState(() {
            allRecipes = searchRecipes;
          });
          String name, about, image, ingred, instruc;
        Query query = recipeRef.child("recipes").orderByChild("name").equalTo(searchVal.trim());
        query.once().then((snapshot) {
            snapshot.value.forEach((key, value){
              name = value["name"].toString().trim();
              image = value["image"].toString().trim();
              about = value["about"].toString().trim();
              instruc = value["instruction"].toString().trim();
              ingred = value["ingred"].toString().trim();
              searchRecipes.add(new Recipes(key, name, ingred, instruc, about,image));
            });
        });
```

**Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!**

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `Scaffold` in a `WillPopScope` widget. Pass `_onBackPressed()` to the widget's `onWillPop` parameter.

Updated

```
Future<bool> _onBackPressed() async {
    if(_isSearching == true){
      setState(() {
        _isSearching = false;
        // maybe clear search text, update recipe list, etc.
      });
      return false;
   }else {
     return true; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: I allready did this, but doesn't work, it is just stuck and don't do anything

Comment: Before returning false, call your search text,  set _isSearching = false, and set any variables related to the view back to the non-searching values (ie recipe list).

Comment: Sorry I didn't got it, where I should do this?

Comment: Should I do this in onBack method?

Comment: This should be called when onWillPop() is call in the WillPopScope widget.

Comment: What's the error? Are you willing to share the full code for this particular view/page?

Comment: It is still stuck, and when I enter the item and go back twice, it giving me an error

Comment: error message: 
 ` EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The getter 'image' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: image`

Comment: Don't call searchRecipes("") in this method. Call searchController.clear(). I would also not store searchRecipes in allRecipes. Simply check the value of _isSearching to determine which list to display.